# Keylogging Structure/Flow

Tags: javascript, vbscript, add-on, keylogger

So this question is to understand possibilities and flow, not to have someone write me all my code.

**Problem:** We have an old and inefficient program we use for our company. The company will not invest in changing it, and will not allow for anyone to touch or update it.

**Ultimate Goal:** Write *AddOnProgram* that serves as an 'add-on' tool to an unmodifiable existing program our company uses. Let's say I type in the SKU field '10043', this *CorporateProgram.exe* returns: 'Oranges.' This is nice, however, it does not tell me how many oranges I have. I then need to manually search somewhere else for that information. The *AddOnProgram* will capture that the user typed '10043' into the SKU field inside of *CorporateProgram.exe*, do the searching itself, and return 'Quantity: 7' inside of *AddOnProgram*.

**Requirements:** When a user is typing into *CorporateProgram.exe*, I want to capture what they are typing and where in which field they are typing in *CorporateProgram.exe*. If the user is typing in any other program, I do not want to capture their keystrokes.

**Means:**

1. I currently envision a background script running which on every
   Windows Process Focus switch activates and determines if
   *CorporateProgram.exe* has now gained focus. If it has, then it will trigger the keystroke recording. If it has been switched to a window
   other than *CorporateProgram.exe* then it will lay dormant until the
   next Windows Process Focus switch.
2. When the user is typing inside of *CorporateProgram.exe*, I don't believe I will have any method to determine in which of the 12 fields they are typing. Are they typing '10043' in the SKU LOOKUP, or are they typing '10043' into zip code? Since *CorporateProgram.exe* is not sizeable, all fields will always be x and y away from the top left corner of the program. I envision mapping these coordinates, capturing the mouse click in relationship to where it occurred inside of *CorporateProgram.exe* and comparing that click to the mapping. so 25 by 100 pixel click from the top left means the following keystrokes are being typed into SKU, while 50 by 100 pixel click from the top left means they are typing into ZIP.

**Language:** I am not the best coder, but can figure stuff out eventually. I prefer to stay in VBScript/javascript. From my understanding though, these do not offer out of browser keyboard/click capture.

Am I missing anything here? Is this not even possible? I appreciate any and all constructive thoughts and responses.

Comment: Sounds about right to me but you also have to consider if they use the tab key instead of clicking on a field.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind while doing mapping.